# How to allow direct user input links the Facebook way?

Tags: social-network, navigation

Does Drupal offer the possibility to have users input a link the Facebook way? In other words, showing directly a summary kind of view of the linked page?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [oembed](http://oembed.com/), there is a [Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed) for it as well, that offers integration to media and some other modules.

> This module will allow your Drupal site to embed content from
>   oEmbed-providers as well as for the site to become an oEmbed-provider
>   itself so that other oEmbed-enabled websites can easily embed your
>   content.

This won't give you a facebook experience out of the box, you still have to configure quiet a lot, you might want to read up on this: [#2108973 Making oEmbed module work with WYSIWYG and CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/node/2108973), which also links [#2269433: Support URLs on a line by themselves in ckeditor/WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/node/2269433).

Comment: thanks, will investigate when I overcome other problems of higher priority.

Comment: Finally I have had the chance to look at oembed, but it doesn't seem at all to do anything near what Facebook does: visitors (or myself for now) just adding a link when viewing a page (NOT editing!) and hit a button.
I expected to find an additional content-type field option, offering this form kind of field plus its corresponding button. 
But oEmbed does not even appear in the "select a field-type" options.
On the pages you mention they basically seem to be worried about embedding Youtube and Vimeo, while this is alread splendidly covered by Media or Googtube. Don't understand this oembed...

Comment: oembed should work for comments as far as I know